# How to use null safe operator in drools decision table

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

Please let me know how to use ".?" (null safe operator) in drools decision table(Spreadsheet). Attached my spreadsheet, where for mdcl object I need to add null safe operator. Please let me know if I need to add additional information, as I'm new to Drools.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The null-safe operator in Drools is `!.`, not `.?` - see the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e8051). You can use it inside decision tables just as you would when writing rules.

In your example, change the condition from `mdcl.MDCL_Health.get("MDCL").Value` to `mdcl!.MDCL_Health.get("MDCL").Value` to only fire the rule if `mdcl` is not null.