# Drools 5.6 mvel null safe property navigation

Tags: java, drools, mvel

I am trying to upgrade drools from version 5.1 to 5.6, in 5.1 we used mvel null safe property access as below, but after upgrading mvel property access operator (.?) no more recognised by drools. Is there any other way to achieve this in 5.6? Thanks.

```
rule "Hello world"
    salience -1
    dialect "mvel"
when
    $c : Hello ( eval( a.?b.?c.?d == null ) )
then
    invalidate($c, "d is missing");
end
```

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947371/how-to-use-null-safe-operator-in-drools-decision-table) helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use `!.`, available in 5.5.0, possibly earlier.

Comment: Thanks Laune, the issue with '!.' is it will only validate the property 'd' in my example, if a, b, c are not null, if lets say b is null it wont treat it as d is missing.